# apache2 enable ssl on subdirectory

Tags: apache2, ssl

I just turned on ssl on my server, if I type on the browser `https://myserver` I get main apache welcome page if I use `https://myserver/mydir` I get a 404 error, if I simply use `http://myserver/mydir` I get right content. How can I resolve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Simply editing `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl` and changing the path under the tag `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` voice *DocumentRoot* fixed my issue.

Comment: What does voice mean in this sentence?

Comment: I mean item excuse me but english is not my first language

Comment: No problem, @haltman.  I was just having trouble understanding what you were referring to as I occasionally configure Apache but not a lot.  Thanks for the clarification.